# Systemd not working with syncthing

Tags: software-installation

[image]

[image]

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I do not see a question just two link urls.

Comment: Systemd is working. The syncthing service is failing for some reason. Someone had a similar problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776003/fixing-a-systemd-service-203-exec-failure-no-such-file-or-directory#45778018